# Unity3D build stuck on scene 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

after I remove the `Google Mobile Ads` plugin, my projects build get stuck at **"Building Scene 0"**

[image]

Very Strange:

1)I have tried to create **a new blank scene** and remove all other scenes but still **got this stuck**...

2) **I have tried to rollback the projects** and use assets that previously successfully build, **but now it can not build and get stuck too.**

Is there any way to debug this thing? or way to fix this?

**Note: I'm using Unity 2019.2.10f1**

Do I need to reinstall Unity?

Editor Log:

> Opening scene 'Assets/z_scene/ID/Main/EN_Main_Menu_NEW.unity'
>   LightmapEditorSettings: switching bake backend from 1 to 0.
>   Unloading 154 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
>   Loaded scene 'Assets/z_scene/ID/Main/EN_Main_Menu_NEW.unity'
>     Deserialize:            364.249 ms
>     Integration:            25.758 ms
>     Integration of assets:  289.124 ms
>     Thread Wait Time:       49.159 ms
>     Total Operation Time:   728.290 ms
>   System memory in use before: 135.9 MB.
>   System memory in use after: 132.5 MB.
>
> Unloading 132 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 4171.
>   Total: 25.561800 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.641300 ms CreateObjectMapping: >0.499200 ms MarkObjects: 22.025800 ms  DeleteObjects: 1.393500 ms)
>
> [00:00:00] Enlighten: Precompute started.
>   Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
>    Thread -> id: 1a10 -> priority: 1 
>   [00:00:00] Enlighten: Finished 1 Layout Systems job (0.00s execute, 0.00s >integrate, 0.02s wallclock)
>   [00:00:00] Enlighten: Finished 1 Tetrahedralize Probes job (0.02s execute, >0.00s integrate, 0.03s wallclock)
>   [00:00:00] Enlighten: Precompute took 0.045671 seconds.
>   Enlighten scene contents:   0 geometries.   0 instances.   0 systems.   0 probe groups.   0 cube maps. Scene is up-to-date.
>   [00:00:00] Enlighten: Bake started.
>   [Optix] removing context.
>   [PathTracer] building lightmap data asset.
>   [PathTracer] Total bake time: 0.014201, raw bake time: 0.000000
>   gi::BakeBackendSwitch: Clear() active clients.
>   [EnlightenBakeManager] m_Clear = false;
>   [PathTracer] building lightmap data asset.
>   gi::BakeBackendSwitch: switching bake backend from 3 to 0.
>   [PathTracer] building lightmap data asset.
>   [00:00:01] Enlighten: Finished 2 Bake Runtime jobs (0.22s execute, 0.00s >integrate, 0.24s wallclock)
>   [00:00:01] Enlighten: Bake took 0.237899 seconds.
>   [00:00:01] Enlighten: LightingDataAsset started.
>   Collecting Enlighten data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to disable the Lightmap Auto Generate checkbox in Window/Rendering/Lighting Setting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Rendering > Lighting settings then unckeck Baked Global Illumin.